# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors for earthquake modeling

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

[image: Here is an introduction to an earthquake modeling problem for a MATLAB project I'm working on:]

[image: This is the part of the problem I'm currently stuck on:]

My instructor explicitly stated that, because we are asked to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a $7\times 7$ matrix, MATLAB would be easiest to use. The equation $(1)$ is intended to resemble a mass-on-spring system, so I'm aware of how to find the natural frequency of the system, and I'm also aware that it's undamped. In other words, I can interpret and solve the equation to an extent.

What I'm specifically struggling with is writing the model as a *second* order system and, as a result, finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the system. Any coding help, or for that matter any help at all, would be greatly appreciated.